# How do you stop scrolling to top when grid store is reloaded

Tags: extjs3

I have an app that uses ExtJS 3.3.0.  It uses an EditorGridPanel in which after the store is reloaded - I would like it to preserve the scroll position of the grid rather than sending it back up to the top.

Because this is an earlier version of ExtJS - this DOES NOT work:

```
viewConfig: {
   preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
}
```

So far the only thing I can come up with is to save the position of the scroll bar prior to loading - and then reset the position once the reload is complete.

I can get as far as saving the position:

```
var scrollPos;

bodyscroll: function(sl, st) {
    scrollPos = st;
},
```

However I can't figure out how to set the position afterwards.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple ways to do this but one way is to use the scroller element, which is accessible through the grid's gridview. See fiddle here: [Grid scoll save/restore](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s8d).

To get scroll value (which you've already got figured out):

```
var top = grid.getView().scroller.getScroll().top;
```

To restore:

```
grid.getView().scroller.scrollTo('top',top);
```

Comment: Bless you.  Such a simple solution but I just couldn't find anything that worked.

Thanks again.